# vbscript excel creating worksheets

Tags: vbscript, excel-2007

excel 2007

i have the following which happily creates a workbook and worksheet.  How can i create another worksheet in the same workbook?

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible = False

Set XLDoc = objExcel.Workbooks.Add

Set XLSheet = XLDoc.Worksheets(1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
```